# Xcode 6 , iOS 9 UIlabel truncates

Tags: xcode, ios9

When I am building my iPad application with XCode 6.4 and running on iOS 9 device, most of the `UILabel` are truncated and the system font is changed to San Francisco font (default iOS 9 font).

I have tried to fix this by overiding `UIfont` functions but of no use as some of `UILabel` are not having outlet connections.

```
+ (UIFont *)boldSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {

    return [UIFont fontWithName:HELVETICA_BOLD size:fontSize];
}

+ (UIFont *)systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {
    return [UIFont fontWithName:HELVETICA size:fontSize];

}
```

Can any one help me to sort this issues out.

Comment: Are you drawing your label in code or is it in Interface Builder? I'll wager interface builder and make a few suggestions. 1) Make sure you've set constraints for your scene in Interface Builder. 2) If your font is too big, you might consider using Autoshrink. You can shrink to a minimum font size or a minimum scale.

Comment: Most of my code is interface builder to set constraints it will take considerable amount of time ..Is there any other way to update the font?

Comment: You should be able to update the font thru IB. In IB, click your label, then look on right side of the screen and on the 3rd or 4th icon over, you should see a setting to update the font on your label

Comment: Thank you will do accordingly